# Only numbers and decimal Directive not working - Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am making a directive that allows only decimal numbers and that is only up to 2 places.

But it is not working as expected. Stackblitz can be found as below

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6akpxb?file=src/app/app.component.html)

The errors that I am facing are as below:

- I can not use keys like <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> etc.
- Once you have types in input box then move cursor before decimal, you will not be able to type :(
- This solution does not work in Safari browser iPad (Why?)

Comment: Listening and blocking keydown events is not really a good practice. Try listening to the change-event instead, this would solve all your problems with hotkeys and stuff.

Comment: can u please do a stackblitz please

Comment: @GiacomoVoß that would be the same idea for me byt onchange does not work for somea reasons. Actually it works but on lost focus.

Comment: Nevermind. Change-Event does only trigger on blur, not as you press the key.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emgasp)

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDecimalNumber]'
})
export class DecimalNumberDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    let e = <KeyboardEvent>event;

    if ([8, 9, 13, 27, 46].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
      // Allow: Ctrl+A
      (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
      // Allow: Ctrl+C
      (e.keyCode === 67 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
      // Allow: Ctrl+V
      (e.keyCode === 86 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
      // Allow: Ctrl+X
      (e.keyCode === 88 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
      // Allow: home, end, left, right
      (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
      // let it happen, don't do anything
      return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event']) onKeyup(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.validateFields(event);
  }

  @HostListener('paste', ['$event']) blockPaste(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.validateFields(event);
  }

  //Todo For limit Parse Int
  validateFields(event) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let numberRegEx = /^[0-9]+$/;
      if (!numberRegEx.test(this.el.nativeElement.value)) {
        this.el.nativeElement.value = "";
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }, 100)
  }

}
```

Comment: could you check now please?